# Why do I get this "syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER" error message from my Ruby code?

Tags: ruby

Can someone please explain me why this code not working? I dont realy know much about ruby yet so hope you can help. It says I have syntax error in `puts multi[is]`:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '<' puts multi[is]
```

Here's the code:

```
        # multi = Array.new
        # multi[0] = Array.new(2, 'hello') 
        # # multi[1] = Array.new(2, 'world')
        # puts(multi[0])
        # puts(multi[1])

        multi = ['hest','hund','kat','fugl'] # names of animals
        for i in multi # convert to 
          is = i.to_i
          is++
          # puts(i. inspect
          puts multi[is]   # her i have error says  syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '<' puts
          multi[is]
        end


        food = Array.new # a new arry

        # 0 milk  names for food
        # 1 ost
        # 2 kod
        # 3 ris
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `is++` is the one causing error. Just write it `is+=1`. In ruby there is no [`--` or `++`](http://docs.ruby-doc.com/docs/Newcomers/ruby.html#operators)  operator.

Straight from the documentation :

> *Ruby has no pre/post increment/decrement operator. For instance, x++ or x-- will fail to parse. More importantly, ++x or --x will do nothing! In fact, they behave as multiple unary prefix operators: -x == ---x == -----x == ...... To increment a number, simply write x += 1.*

I re-written your code with some modification :

```
multi = ['hest','hund','kat','fugl'] # names of animals
index=-1
for name in multi
  p "#{name} at #{index+=1}"
end
# >> "hest at 0"
# >> "hund at 1"
# >> "kat at 2"
# >> "fugl at 3"
```

Comment: thanks now i see like is+=1  the one is the place of the animal names  so 1 is the hund

Comment: @Mark I don't know why you wrote the code and what stuffs you are going to do as those were not the part of your post. I just concentrated why the error came and accordingly tried to fix it. Now you can play with your code as you like.

Comment: im very new to this so , did not realy know what to post hee, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Arup has already answered the question, but I wish to add the *Rubyish* tinge to your code which doesn't follow it's conventions.

```
multi = ['hest','hund','kat','fugl'] # names of animals

multi.each_with_index do |m, i|
  puts "#{i+1} #{m}"
end
```

`each_with_index` is Ruby *enumerator* which provides you with two block variables, one for element (here, `m`) and one for index of corresponding element(here, `i`)

Keep rubying. :)